# Wie beugt man „Pentachoron”?

Tags: declension, mathematics

Ich denke, dass die Mehrzahl *Pentachora* lautet. Wie wäre es im Genitiv und Dativ?

```
     S          P
N  -choron   -chora
G  -chorons    ?
D  -choron     ?
A  -choron   -chora
```

So sicher wäre ich auch nicht, dass meine Vermuttung für Genitiv Singular richtig ist. (Ein *Pentachoron* ist ein 4-Simplex; leider brauche ich hier diesen griechischen Namen.)

Comment: Ich würde alle Pluralformen mit *-en* bilden, analog *Amphoren*.

Comment: @Janka: Dein Vergleich hinkt beidbeinig. Denn die beiden Wörter lauten im Singular *»das Pentachor**on**«* und *»die Amphor**e**«*. Ich sehe da überhaupt keine Ähnlichkeiten

Comment: Der deutsche Singular könnte genausogut *Pentachor* lauten. Damit da keiner an fünf Chöre denkt oder an einen Fünfklang (Pentachor**d**), belässt man es beim *Pentachoron*. Der Zwölfflächner heißt auch nicht *Dodekahedron*, sondern *Dodeka**eder***. Es gibt kein System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Der Plural lautet allem Anschein nach tatsächlich *»Pentachora«* (im Nominativ), wie man auf einer Website über [Platonische Polychora](http://www.polytope.de/plat4.html) und auch auf [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentachoron) nachlesen kann. Allerdings wird auf der erstgenannten Site die Singularform *»Polychor«* verwendet, die offenbar auch geläufig ist (siehe [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polychor)).

Man kommt den Beugungen recht gut auf die Schliche, wenn man ganz einfach Sätze bildet, in denen die Wörter in den jeweiligen Formen vorkommen.

- Nominativ

  > *Sing:* Das Penta**choron** ist das einfachste Poly**chor**.
  >   *Plur:* Alle Penta**chora** sind Poly**chora**.
- Genitiv

  > *Sing:* Die Ränder eines Penta**chorons** (oder eines Poly**chors**) sind dreidimensionale Polyeder.
  >   *Plur:* Die Ränder aller Penta**chora** (sowie aller Poly**chora**) sind dreidimensionale Polyeder.
- Dativ

  > *Sing:* Der Rand von einem Penta**choron** (oder einem Poly**chor**) besteht aus mehreren dreidimensionalen Polyedern.
  >   *Plur:* Die Ränder von allen Penta**chora** (sowie von allen Poly**chora**) sind dreidimensionale Polyeder.
- Akkusativ

  > *Sing:* Es ist nicht möglich, ein Penta**choron** (oder ein Poly**chor**) aus Knetmasse herzustellen.
  >   *Plur:* Es ist nicht möglich, Penta**chora** (oder Poly**chora**) aus Knetmasse herzustellen.

Also:

```
     S          P  
N  -choron   -chora  
G  -chorons  -chora  
D  -choron   -chora  
A  -choron   -chora
```

oder:

```
     S          P  
N  -chor   -chora  
G  -chors  -chora  
D  -chor   -chora  
A  -chor   -chora
```

Vergleiche auch:

- [Oxymoron](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Oxymoron)
- [Adiaphoron](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Adiaphoron)

Comment: Und wieso nicht Pentachorons oder Pentachorone? Auf ~chora wäre ich nicht durch Satzbildung gekommen. Ein Xylophon, zwei Xylophone. Ein Semikolon, zwei Semikolons.

Comment: @userunknown: Auch: Ein Semikolon, zwei Semikola.

Comment: Zwei Semikola, drei Africola, vier Gorgonzola - solange Nichtlateiner und Nichtgriechen kein Nachschlagewerk dabeihaben (Akku leer), müssen sie den Plural ohne Hilfe bilden, und bevor ich Semikolii sage, Semicolae oder Semikolonnen ... :)

Comment: Das ist aus dem Griechischen: *-on* wird plural *-a*. Sowie in Latein *-um* zu *-a* wird (Museum, Musea). Kann man auch als Nichtlateiner usw. lernen. Gilt übrigens nicht für Polygon, usw.

Answer (score 1):

Wenn man sich an der Deklination von Oxymoron [gemäß Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Oxymoron) orientiert, heißt es im Genitiv Plural *der Pentachora* und im Dativ Plural *den Pentachora*.

Das ist natürlich irgendwo inkonsequent, denn die altgriechischen Formen lauten anders. Ich persönlich würde eigentlich *Pentachoren* bevorzugen, aber der Duden sagt etwas anderes.

Comment: *»Das ist natürlich irgendwo inkonsequent ...«* Nein, ist es nicht. Die deutsche Grammatik hat keinen Grund, sich an der Grammatik fremder Sprachen zu orientieren. Daher bestellt man nicht zwei *pizze* sondern zwei *Pizzas* oder *Pizzen*. Und in den Gebärkliniken schreien keine *babies* sondern *Babys*. Und um davon reden zu können, dass zwei *Kimonos* im Kleiderschrank hängen, muss man auch keinen Japanischkurs belegen.
Schon die Singularform im Nominativ ist im deutschen anders als im Griechischen: Deutsch: *»Polychoro**n**«* griechisch: *»polychoro**s**«*.

Comment: Inkonsequent ist es, weil die altgriechische Pluralendung übernommen wird (die deutsche Grammatik kennt von Haus aus keine Pluralformen auf -a), was aber auf die Nominativendung beschränkt bleibt, die bei Neutra gleichzeitig Akkusativendung ist.